# Doubt in calculation of series: $\sum_{k=2}^\infty{a_k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $Sn=\frac{2n^2+1}{n+n^2}$ is the nth partial sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{a_k}$

How can I calculate:

$\sum_{k=2}^\infty{a_k}$

Comment: what is the doubt?

Comment: The last one is just $2-a_1=2-S_1$. Where did the $2$ came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that
$$ S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k = \frac{2n^2 + 1}{n + n^2}$$
So,
$$ S_n - S_1 = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k - \sum_{k = 1}^1 a_k =  \sum_{k = 2}^n a_k$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k = 2}^\infty a_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 2}^n a_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} (S_n - S_1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2n^2 + 1}{n + n^2} - \frac{2(1)^2 + 1}{1 + 1^2} \right) = 2 - \frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
In other words, just subtract the first term from $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k$ in order to get $\sum_{k = 2}^\infty a_k$. The first term is gotten from evaluating $S_1$.

Comment: thank you I have understood everything.